highchart throwing build error after upgrading Angular from 7 to 14
we have upgraded Angular app from version 7  to 14 and also highcharts as well.
now we are getting build errors as many of the Properties and events giving build errors.
I have tried to downgrade and upgrade version but didt worked for me .also tried to handle error to ignore via es lint but not succeed.

To which version of Highcharts and Highcharts Angular did you upgrade? It's possible that these versions are incompatible. You can take a look at compatibility table, where it states that Highcharts v11.0.0 or higher requires Angular >= 16.0.0: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular?tab=readme-ov-file#general-prerequisites.

we have updated highcharts  -"highcharts": "^6.2.0","highcharts-angular": "^2.3.1","highcharts-custom-events": "^3.0.2", to  "highcharts": "^8.2.2","highcharts-angular": "^2.9.0","highcharts-custom-events": "^3.0.2",

It is hard to tell what can be wrong without seeing the config. Simply upgrading packages version doesn't result in an error on a simple demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-mcsdvu?file=package.json. When upgrading to never version of Highcharts, it might be necessary to update some properties or methods, as they might have changed in latter release.
